# how do I force my custom tslint rule to use the same version of the typescript module as the one tslint is using

Tags: typescript, npm, tslint

I'm most likely doing something very wrong, but I can't figure out what.

In my custom rule, I'm checking the SyntaxKind of a Node to control my flow, like so:

```
import * as ts from "typescript"

function processPropertyName(pn: ts.PropertyName) {
    switch (pn.kind) {
        case ts.SyntaxKind.Identifier:
        case ts.SyntaxKind.StringLiteral:
            //doX
            break
        case ts.SyntaxKind.NumericLiteral:
            //doY
            break
    }
}
```

I have installed typescript as a module
this works fine when I'm developing and testing the rule. However, when I publish the package and use it in another project the SyntaxKind values are messed up. for example: NumericalLiteral has value 8 in my environment, but not in the consuming environment. Most likely because another version of the typescript package is used.
But how can I make sure that the typescript package that I am importing in my rule file is the same as the one that is being used to parse the source file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

never mind, I found the solution :)

Comment: just kidding about leaving it at that. It seems that I need to install tslint and typescript as peerDependencies